# Email a chartjs graph in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js

Email a graph made in chartjs to an email address. Send graph as attachment or in body of email. Please let me know how to attach graph to email, in laravel. Any source code will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem where I wanted to Chart.js charts as an image.  I built a web service that takes a Chart.js config and returns a PNG image.

The service is called [QuickChart](https://quickchart.io/) and it's [open source](https://github.com/typpo/quickchart).

Take a Chart.js config like this:

```
{
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dogs',
      data: [ 50, 60, 70, 180, 190 ]
    }, {
      label: 'Cats',
      data: [ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 ]
    }]
  }
}
```

And put it into a URL:

[https://quickchart.io/chart?c={type:'bar',data:{labels:['January','February','March','April','May'],datasets:[{label:'Dogs',data:[50,60,70,180,190]},{label:'Cats',data:[100,200,300,400,500]}]}}](https://quickchart.io/chart?bkg=white&c=%7Btype:%27bar%27,data:%7Blabels:[%27January%27,%27February%27,%27March%27,%27April%27,%27May%27],datasets:[%7Blabel:%27Dogs%27,data:[50,60,70,180,190]%7D,%7Blabel:%27Cats%27,data:[100,200,300,400,500]%7D]%7D%7D)

The `/chart` endpoint returns this PNG:

[image: Example image chart]

Don't forget to URL encode the chart config.  To use this in PHP, use the [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to encode the chart definition:

```
$chart = "{
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dogs',
      data: [ 50, 60, 70, 180, 190 ]
    }, {
      label: 'Cats',
      data: [ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 ]
    }]
  }
}";

$encoded = urlencode($chart);
$imageUrl = "https://quickchart.io/chart?c=" . $encoded;

// Embed $imageUrl in your email
```